# Download zip file from web, unzipped and import to data set using sas

Tags: download, sas, unzip

I want to download one zip file from web and unzipped and import that file to sas data set for further use.

For unzipping i use below sas code.. But result is nothing with no error.

```
data _null_;
x "cd C:\Program Files\7-Zip ";
X "7z.exe e C:\Users\Ravinder\Downloads\Compressed\*.zip -o C:\sasdata\New";
run;
```

Please help to do the same.

ravinder kumar

Comment: You aren't providing enough information to help you, and honestly this doesn't look like a programming problem in any case.  Your SAS code is fine.  You likely have a problem with the 7z and/or the download.

Comment: @Joe Not sure I agree - the poster wants to do this task programmatically via SAS.  While SAS may not be the best tool for the job it's still a programming question in my mind.

Comment: @RobPenridge The issue here, though, is that the SAS code isn't in error; it's most likely something related to the 7zip call and/or the file download (the latter of which might be SAS related, but there's no evidence either way).  In any event the question is not answerable in its present form given the lack of information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your command from a command prompt?  Did it work?  I would recommend running the command like this rather than changing the folder first:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e C:\Users\Ravinder\Downloads\Compressed\*.zip -o C:\sasdata\New
```

When you run the above command from SAS use single quotes as your string delimiter for the command like so:

```
data _null_;
  X '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e C:\Users\Ravinder\Downloads\Compressed\*.zip -o C:\sasdata\New';
run;
```

If it is still not working as expected from SAS, then the easiest way to debug IMO is to put the command in a batch file (.bat), and then at the end of the file put a line that simply says `pause`.  The pause command will tell windows to keep the batch file window open until you close it.  The window will give you full visibility of what happened when you ran the command.  Try running the batch file from SAS instead of running the command directly.

Note that you may also need to specify the following SAS options if you want SAS to wait for the unzip to finish before your SAS program continues processing:

options noxwait xsync;

`noxwait` tells SAS to close the command window automatically once the command has run, and `xsync` tells SAS to wait for the command to finish running before continuing to process.  Note that sometimes when extracting files, the command can finish but the file will still not exist on disk due to either network copying and/or caching.  If you want to be *absolutely* sure, you should probably check for the existence of the file and/or tell sas to `sleep()` for a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

here is my problem solution.. File download to c:\sasdata location.

```
data _null_;
x "cd c:\sasdata";
x "curl -A 'Mozilla/4.0' -O http://nseindia.com/content/indices/histdata/CNX%20NIFTY&FRNAME-&FRNAME..csv";
run;
```